# CupertinoPicker the middle part is blocked

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Plz check screenshot, with Text it does work, but when I change the widget to `SvgPicture.asset`, the middle part will be missing... why...

```
final wormItems = [
  AssetsResources.iconMystery,
  AssetsResources.iconMale,
  AssetsResources.iconFemale,
];

CupertinoPicker(
          // diameterRatio: 1,
          selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(
            background: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.1),
          ),
          scrollController: thirdScrollController,
          looping: true,
          itemExtent: 120,
          onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
              setState(() => this.index = index);
          },
          // children: wormItems.map((item) => item).toList(),
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            wormItems.length,
                (index) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                child: Center(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(wormItems[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

***Update***

I test with followings, it seems that cupertinopicker does not support svgpicture.asset display in the middle but works in the up/ bottom part, it is strange:

this container is element from list：

```
  child: Container(
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/icon_male.svg'),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: AssetImage('assets/cards/3.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

here is result:
[image]

Comment: Do you have an `initialitem` set in your `thirdScrollController`? change this and see if it works.

Comment: Hi MendelG I do have intialItem in controller, plz check my update, it seems svgPicture is not ok for cupertinoPicker